# How to perform an image manipulation on a folder of images?

Tags: python, image

I have code to add a border on a single image, but need to make it work on a folder of images. How do I apply a border to a folder of images? (Am using Cloud 9)

```
       def add_border(original,new):
           img = Image.open(original)
           img_with_border = ImageOps.expand(img,border=40,fill='black')
           img_with_border.save(new)
```

Comment: Loop over the directory that you want to operate on using `os.listdir` or similar, then run the function on the image files there.

Comment: how do you do that?